# Lower semicontinuity of the rank for a map of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, semicontinuous-functions

In Nitsure's [*Cohomology of the moduli of parabolic vector bundles*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02837250.pdf), we have the following Remark on page $62$:

> **([Remark 1.2)** Let $E$ be a vector bundle on a scheme $S$ and let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be subbundles. Let $\Phi:F_1\to E/F_2$ be the natural map. Then the function $s\to \operatorname{rank}_{\kappa(s)}\Phi(s) $ is lower semicontinuous on $S$. (Equivalently the function $s\to \operatorname{dim}_{\kappa(s)}F_1(s)\cap F_2(s) $ is upper semicontinuous).

1. What is exactly the natural map $\Phi$?
2. How can we prove this remark? Is there any reference?

Thank you.

Comment: $\Phi$ is the composition of the natural inclusion map $F_1\to E$ and the quotient map $E\to E/F_2$.

Comment: Thank you @CaptainLama for your help with question 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question has already been answered in the comments: take the composition of the inclusion $F_1\to E$ and the projection $E\to E/F_2$.

The second question can be dealt with locally. Choose an affine open $\operatorname{Spec} R\subset S$ where $F_1$ and $E/F_2$ are free, so that $\Phi$ is locally represented by a matrix $M$ with entries in $R$. Then the condition that $\operatorname{rank} \Phi(s) < r$ is that all the determinants of the $r\times r$ minors of $M$ vanish at $s$. This is a closed condition, which exactly implies lower semicontinuity of rank. (See for instance characterization 3 on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity#Lower_semicontinuity).)

Comment: Thank you @KReiser, it's clear to me now